# Periodic bleep in train station

Tags: uk, trains, train-stations

I've been travelling recently and at multiple stations there have been speakers emitting a bleep every second. (For example Stansted Airports station).

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Sound markings for the blind?

Comment: Do you have a recording? I can't think what this would be.

Comment: Might have found one myself - is it the very faint beep every second you hear at this point in this video? https://youtu.be/gRu9_OWfr-g?t=102 I definitely can't think what that would be, besides perhaps interference in some speaker system from a mechanical clock, as @anon suggested.

Comment: @Muzer yep that is it faintly in that video. I'll record it next time I'm there regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Is the bleep louder every 10 seconds, even louder every minute, even louder every 10 minutes, even louder every hour, and loudest at 10:00:00, 20:00:00, and 00:00:00? If so, it might be the mechanism of the station clocks. Many of the older clocks with digital display make a clicking sound every second as one or more of the six figures changes.

Comment: We thought it might be that but the sounds were coming from a speaker rather than the clock. Additionally they were all the same loudness. Good idea though.

Comment: Based on the video I found, I suspect this is in fact the answer - some mechanical clock system was perhaps inducing stray current in some dodgy speaker cabling somewhere, thus resulting in this noise. I could be wrong though, it's a very weird sound, and this is just a guess. I certainly can't think of any other purpose.